# PyQT QtCore.SIGNAL

Tags: python, pyqt4

Is there any list of the signals that can be use with PyQT4 or at least there is one that is the opposite of lostFocus()?

Comment: From what class is lostFocus()?

Comment: is part of QtCore.SIGNALS i think

Answer (score 2):

There is a `QFocusEvent` event generated by 'QWidget', but not a signal.  There is however a convenient event handler that catches these events: [`focusInEvent`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#focusInEvent).

You can add your own signal by reimplementing this handler.  For example (not tested):

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    focus_in = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, name='focusIn')

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.focus_in.emit()
        QtGui.QWidget.focusInEvent(self, event)
```

Now you get a `focusIn` signal.

Comment: Since focusIn has declared int argument, it gives an error when you try to emit it without int argument.